# Windows Gadget cUrl

Tags: windows, curl, windows-desktop-gadgets

i developed a **windows gadget** to get basic information from a website, problem is to get this information we have to connect to the website, i solved this problem using curl with a php script

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
$curl_options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
);
curl_setopt_array($curl_handle, $curl_options);
$content = curl_exec($curl_handle);
```

but i want the gadget to be **independent** from this php script so i am asking if i can use curl with an other language supported (javascript i have cross domain origin problem)

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The windows gadget engine is actually immune to the cross domain origin policy.  You can use xmlhttprequest.